# AnchorPane listener in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I am trying to add a listener ***with condition*** in JavaFX but my listener is never firing.

```
    @FXML
    private AnchorPane inputRoot;

    // Listener 1 - This works!
    inputRoot.widthProperty().addListener(e -> {

        if(inputRoot.getWidth() < 600) {
            System.out.println("Root is smaller than 600");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Root is greater than 600");
        }
    });

    // Listener 2 - This does not work!
    inputRoot.widthProperty().greaterThan(600).addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        if (!newValue) {
            System.out.println("> Root is greater than 600");
        } else {
            System.out.println("> Root is smaller than 600");
        }
    });
```

As you see above - I need *Listener 2* to work so it executes whenever the condition is met. There are no errors - just nothing happens.

Any clarification would be tremendous. Thank you

**UPDATE**
Per James_D explanation - keeping reference of the binding fixes the issue.

```
private BooleanBinding widthProperty = inputRoot.widthProperty().greaterThan(600);

        widthProperty.addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {

            if (!newValue) {
                System.out.println("> Root is greater than 600");
            } else {
                System.out.println("> Root is smaller than 600");
            }
        });
```

Comment: Assuming `inputRoot` is getting wider that 600, you might be running into the ["accidental garbage collection"](http://tomasmikula.github.io/blog/2015/02/10/the-trouble-with-weak-listeners.html) problem. Post a [MCVE].

Comment: The ObservableValue stores a strong reference to the listener which will prevent the listener from being garbage collected and may result in a memory leak. It is recommended to either unregister a listener by calling removeListener after use or to use an instance of WeakChangeListener avoid this situation.

[BooleanBinding](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/BooleanBinding.html#computeValue--)                                   @James_D

Comment: @moneydhaze This is the opposite problem though: the binding created by the call to `greaterThan(...)` uses a weak listener on the `widthProperty()`. Since there are no references anywhere to that, it's eligible for garbage collection, and gets garbage collected *even though the application logic still requires it*. So, probably (I would need to see a complete example to properly test), the OP needs to explicitly keep a reference to the binding for as long as the listener is required.

Comment: @James_D Thank you - you were on point!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As James_D mentioned, I think it's what he explained

I tried pretty much stuff and just got it to work, by storing the BooleanBinding in the Controller and add a changelistener to the stored binding which makes me thinking that James_D is right with the Garbage Collection problem

```
@FXML
private AnchorPane inputRoot;
private BooleanBinding gt600;

@Override
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
    gt600 = inputRoot.widthProperty().greaterThan(600);
    gt600.addListener((observable, newvalue, oldvalue) -> {
        System.out.println(newvalue.toString());
    });
}
```

Comment: even it returns true as smaller or equal to and false as greater than 600...